# How require only a channel that I need?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

All channels are created on folder `javascript/channels` and by default, all inner this path is loaded.

To not require all I just delete the file `channels/index` that contains:

```js
// Load all the channels within this directory and all subdirectories.
// Channel files must be named *_channel.js.

const channels = require.context('.', true, /_channel\.js$/)
channels.keys().forEach(channels)
```

But how require my channels at pages that I need?

Using `= javascript_pack_tag "channels/my_channel"` at pages that I need doest work.

Which are is the best practices? How keep many channels and require  only where I need?

Answer (score 0):

Channel js file (channel subscriber, to be exact) usually contains something like

```
const channel_subscription = consumer.subscriptions.create({
  channel: 'SomeChannel',
  received: function(data) {...}
});
```

subscription is created when it is executed (at page load by default), but you can make it a function:

```js
function connect_this_exact_channel() {
  return consumer.subscriptions.create(...)
}
```

and it will create the subscription only when the function is called.